# Batch search txt, extract contents, merge contents in a single txt

Tags: batch-processing, batch-file

- "Main" folder

  - Folder-"Other"

    - Folder-"A" 
       Folder-"B" 
       
       (...) 
       Folder-"N"

Hi, I have a Main folder, a secondary folder and its several child named "folder-A, folder-B ... folder-N". Each child has txt files with lots of information in them.

I would like to read each folder (only folders A to N), collect the information within each txt and merge that information to make a Big.txt. The user would also know how many txt files were analysed and merged.

No good results so far. Any help?

```
@echo off
set DRV1=c:\Main\Other
set DRV2=c:\Big
cd %DRV1%
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set /a count=0 
          for %%f in (*.txt) do (
            for /f "delims= " %%a in (%%f) do ( 
            set /a count+=1 
            echo %%a >> %DRV2%\Big.txt
          )
     )
endlocal
echo There were processed %count% txt files ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"no good results"_? What are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of problems here:

- First, you're missing an iteration over the directories you wish to scan for .txt files.
- Then you're trying to read the files line-by-line in the inner `FOR` loop and that's not working as it is - and not necessary too, because you can just use `TYPE` to write/append each .txt file's contents to another file.
- Last, you don't need `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` for this task - *it can even cause problems* if any of the .txt files have an exclamation mark `!` in the filename - exclamation marks will be eaten by the delayed expansion because `CMD.EXE` thinks it's part of a variable name, corrupting the filename and thus causing the contents of the file not to be included in `Big.txt`. By the way, I wouldn't have known that before it hit me while fiddling around for the solution - because I actually had .txt files with an exclamation mark in the filename for testing :)

Long story short, here's what I ended up with:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET DRV1=c:\Main\Other
SET DRV2=c:\Big
SET /a count=0 
:: iterate over all directories in %DRV1%
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%F IN ( 'dir /b /a:d %DRV1%' ) DO ( 
    :: for each directory, iterate over all .txt files
    FOR %%G IN ( %DRV1%\%%F\*.txt ) DO (
        SET /a count+=1 
        TYPE %%G >> %DRV2%\Big.txt
    )
)
ECHO There were processed %count% txt files ...
```